# 1px difference between font size of "Public"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

The font size goes from 14px to 13px when going from for instance the `jobs` tab to the `tags` tab.

`Jobs` tab (the text size is 14px here):

[image]

`Tags` tab (the text size is 13px here):

[image]

The chrome console verifies this.  Size matters.

Comment: is the dropdown a team only thing?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - Yes

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your report. This will be fixed in the next release.

<sub>Copied from a Comment:</sub>

> It is live now

Comment: Sorry about that, I totally forgot to tag it! Thanks for the reminder. It is live now, so I've tagged with status-completed.